# What does this strange line do?

Tags: rust, deobfuscation

A [pull request](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/51059/commits) has been done with a new test for the Rust compiler. It verifies that a strange line can compile:

```
fn main() {
    let val = !((|(..):(_,_),__@_|__)((&*"\\",'@')/**/,{})=={&[..=..][..];})//
    ;
    assert!(!val);
}
```

What does this line do exactly?

Comment: It's worth reading [the whole `weird-exprs.rs` file](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/5ad84cf3fa988e47d5b6b058c2888de076881d5c/src/test/run-pass/weird-exprs.rs) with function names like `zombiejesus` and `evil_lincoln`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let's break it down! First, I reformatted the line to somewhat increase "readability".

```
let val = !(
    (
        |(..): (_, _), __@_| __
    )(
        (
            &*"\\", 
            '@'
        ) /**/, 
        {}
    )
    ==
    {
        &[..=..][..];
    }
)//
;
```

It starts with `let val =` and ends with `//<newline>;`. So it's a simple let-binding of the form `let val = ⟨v⟩;`. Let's discuss what `⟨v⟩` does:

- A negation via the *not* operator: `!( ⟨_⟩ )`

  - A comparison via `==`:  `⟨lhs⟩ == ⟨rhs⟩`

    - ***⟨lhs⟩***: a function call of a closure `( ⟨closure⟩ )( ⟨args⟩ )`

      - ***⟨closure⟩***: a closure definition `|⟨first_param⟩, ⟨second_param⟩| ⟨body⟩`

        - ***⟨first_param⟩***: `(..): (_, _)`. This parameter has a type annotation `(_, _)` meaning that it is a 2-tuple. The pattern (where normally, you would find a single name) is `(..)` which means: a tuple, but ignore all elements of it.
        - ***⟨second_param⟩***: `__@_`. This is a pattern usually known from match bindings: `name @ pattern`. So the actual pattern is `_` (which doesn't bind anything) and the value is bound via `@` to the name `__` (two underscores, which is a kind of valid identifier).
        - ***⟨body⟩***: `__`. This is just the identifier which we bound the second parameter to. So the closure is basically equivalent to `|_, x| x`.
      - ***⟨args⟩***: a list of two arguments with an inline comment `/**/` in between: `⟨first_arg⟩/**/, ⟨second_arg⟩`

        - ***⟨first_arg⟩***: `(&*"\\", '@')`. This is simply a 2-tuple where the first element is a string containing a backslash and the second is the char `'@'`. The `&*` for the first element cancels out.
        - ***⟨second_arg⟩***: `{}`. This is an empty block which has the type `()`. So as second argument, a unit is passed.
    - ***⟨rhs⟩***: a braced block with one statement inside: `{ ⟨stmt⟩; }`. Note that this is a statement, with a semicolon. This means the result is not returned from the block. Instead the block returns `()` just as the empty block `{}`.

      - ***⟨stmt⟩***: an indexing expression `{ &⟨collection⟩[⟨index⟩] }`.

        - ***⟨collection⟩***: `[..=..]`. This is an array with one element. The element is `..= ..` which is a [`RangeToInclusive`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.RangeToInclusive.html) where `end` of the range is the [`RangeFull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html) written `..`.
        - ***⟨index⟩***: `..`. This is just the `RangeFull` again.

---

**So in summary**: we compare the result of calling a closure to a braced block which evaluates to `()`. The closure is basically `|_, x| x` and the second argument we pass to it is `{}` (which evaluates to `()`), so the whole closure calling expression evaluates to `()`.

This means the whole thing is equivalent to:

- `let val = !( () == () );`, which is equivalent to:
- `let val = !( true );`, which is equivalent to:
- **`let val = false;`**